# postNotificationName exc bad access

Tags: ios, xcode, exc-bad-access, nsnotification

I'm receiving a lot of crash log for postNotificationName:

What I'm doing is that I register for notification on viewdidappear and removeObserver on viewdiddisappear. Most of them are crashing just after sendDelegateAnimationDidStop, what calls this method and causing notification to crash? Thanks people.

```
    Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_platform.dylib       0x3b2b04da _platform_memmove$VARIANT$Swift + 185
1  ???                            0x00000008 
2  CoreFoundation                 0x30106b25 _CFXNotificationPost + 1076
3  Foundation                     0x30af1cc5 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 72
4  UIKit                          0x32a38655 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 816
5  UIKit                          0x32a382ef -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 66
6  QuartzCore                     0x32682e0b CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 234
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x3b180d3f _dispatch_client_callout + 22
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x3b1836c3 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 278
9  CoreFoundation                 0x3019b681 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
10 CoreFoundation                 0x30199f4d __CFRunLoopRun + 1308
11 CoreFoundation                 0x30104769 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
12 CoreFoundation                 0x3010454b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
13 GraphicsServices               0x3502e6d3 GSEventRunModal + 138
14 UIKit                          0x32a63891 UIApplicationMain + 1136
15 App                            0x00078c2d main (main.m:21)
```

Comment: May be you can add some codes where you add and remove the observer and also where you post the notification.

Comment: I have too many post notification, posting the code might not help. However all these crash log shows that their iPad has less than 5% ram. Can these be the cause?